# read database table and output to file in scala?

Tags: java, scala

I am newbie in Scala , I am trying to connect sql server database table and output data to a file using ~ as delimiter.
I managed to write below code the problem is while writing to file I can only see one record but where as if I print on screen using println I can see several records, I think I am missing something here need your help guys.
I want to see all the output displayed by println in my output file, as of now I can only see one line of output in output file.

Achieved:-
285~Syed

Expected:-
285~Syed
293~Catherine
295~Kim
2170~Kim
38~Kim
211~Hazem
2357~Sam
297~Humberto
291~Gustavo
299~Pilar

```js
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager, ResultSet}
import java.io._
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
                                                  //> res35: Class[?0] = class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://myip;databaseName=AdventureWorks2014;user=user;password=oracle;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8")
                                                  
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\scalatutorials\\hello.txt"));
    val statement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)                                     
    val rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 10 BusinessEntityID,FirstName FROM AdventureWorks2014.dbo.Person;")
                                                 
    while (rs.next){
    val bussid=rs.getInt("BusinessEntityID")
    val First=rs.getString("FirstName")
    val kop=List(bussid,First)
    val opsql=kop.mkString("~")
    pw.write(opsql)
    println(opsql)
    pw.close
    }                                             //> 285~Syed
                                                  //| 293~Catherine
                                                  //| 295~Kim
                                                  //| 2170~Kim
                                                  //| 38~Kim
                                                  //| 211~Hazem
                                                  //| 2357~Sam
                                                  //| 297~Humberto
                                                  //| 291~Gustavo
                                                  //| 299~Pilar
   conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to close the stream after reading first record. So after writing all the record then you could close the stream like:

```
while (rs.next){
    ...
    ..write(..)
}
//close open resources here and not in while loop.
```